# Unable to produce animated gifs using with_slider_draw()

Tags: animation, slider, maxima

Using wxMaxima v19.05.7 on osx 13.6/15.7 I have no problems creating animated gifs using **with_slider()**. E.g.

```
with_slider(
   t,
   makelist(i,i,0,%e,0.05),
   [sin(x+t), cos(x+t)], [x,0,5]
)$
```

works as expected. However, if I want to plot the function graphs with **with_slider_draw()**

```
with_slider_draw(
    t,
    makelist(i,i,0,%e,0.05),
    explicit(sin(x+t),x,0,5)
)$e
```

I get error messages like:

```
Wxmaxima Error
cant't open file '~/tmp/maxout_4856_55.png'
Error 2. No such file or directory.
```

and the place-holder for the inline graphics within wxMaxima saying

```
Error: cannot render ~/tmp/maxout_4856_55.png
```

There are indeed no **maxout_4856_[01-55].png-files** in ~/tmp/ . The corresponding gnuplot files **data4856.gnuplot** and **maxout4856.gnuplot** however are produced.

What is going wrong here?

1. Why are **no** graphic files produced?
2. Why does wxMaxima ask for **png**-files?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers, Tilda

---

**Edit:** I managed to solve the problem by resetting the terminal in **set_draw_defaults()** So,

```
set_draw_defaults(
     line_width = 2, 
     dimensions = [640,384],
       terminal = pngcairo
)$
with_slider_draw(
t,
makelist(i,i,0,%e,0.05),
   color = steelblue4,
explicit(sin(x+t),x,0,5),
   color = red3,
explicit(cos(x+t),x,0,5)
)$
```

produces the desired **with_slider_draw()**-animation inline that can then be exported as an animated gif:

[Animation of the above plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKela.gif)

Cheers, Tilda